# Export (::Array{Expr,1} to .csv

Tags: csv, julia

Does anyone know a good way to export the type:

```
(::Array{Expr,1}
```

To a .csv?

Here is an example of the Expression that I have in `exp_out`:

```
Expr[3]
    [Decycler(es_close; n=224), 263, 262, 0.04, 62, 147, 104, 201, -3.5, 6.0, 4, 6, "Next_bar_open", "This_bar_on_close", 4.5, 1, 10, "short", 11, 14.0]
    [HurstCoefficient(es_close; n=152, LPPeriod=131), 291, 130, 0.68, 6, 261, 243, 183, -2.0, 4.0, 6, 5, "Next_bar_open", "Next_bar_open", 3.0, 1, 1, "long", 23, 12.5]
    [broadcast(/, ModifiedStochastic(es_close; n=293, HPPeriod=95, LPPeriod=139), RoofingFilterIndicator(es_close; LPPeriod=224, HPPeriod=57)), 222, 134, 0.42, 267, 156, 43, 112, -4.5, 1.0, 3, 2, "Next_bar_open", "This_bar_on_close", 17.5, 8, 1, "long", 26, 4.5]
```

My goal is to export the expresison to a .csv file so that full expression above is contained to one column on export.

```
    using CSV
    CSV.write("C:/Users/yoohoo/expr.csv", exp_out;delim=',')
```

It expands multiple columns on output as its separating by `delim=','` Any ideas how to effectively export this cleanly to 1x column?

Output:

[image]

You see the `delim=','` is separating so that my Expr encroaches on the other columns.

Expected output would not to have it splitting on `delim=','` and have the full Expr in the first ID column.

Comment: What is your current output, and what is your expected output?

Comment: As written, you export the expressions to CSV without their argument and dependency, es_close. You are losing that array unless you also export it or otherwise re-create it.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (MWE). Currently your question is incomprehensible.

Comment: Save my expression as Expr type. Try export it...